# Chrome notification click on Close button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I use notification API to show popup window on Chrome 73:

```
new Notification('', {
    icon: "images/transparent.png",
    image: res,
    requireInteraction: true
});
notification.onclose = function () {
    alert('close')
};
notification.onclick= function () {
    alert('click')
};
notification.onerror= function () {
    alert('error');
};
notification.onnotificationclose = function () {
    alert("close")
};
```

I see this popup:

[image]

But the problem is that if user clicks icon with arrow, then `onclose` is fired, but if user clicks 'Close' aka 'Закрыть' button, no handler is invoked.

How can I handle it? Is it a bug in chrome?

Comment: Can you put a little more info? Like what version of chrome are you using and what are your Notification actions? Are you using a global service worker ? If so, did you try the `'notificationonclose'` event?

Comment: onnotificationclose doesn't help

Comment: Does `notification.addEventListener('close', function () => { ... });` solve the issue?

Comment: no it doesn't, you can test yourself

Comment: I seem this notification like a native notification of Windows 10?

Comment: correct, it is native windows 10, but i'd like to handle this close event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, when you use the Notification API like in your code snippet, you simply cannot handle events that are triggered by clicking the button in a custom way. It seems that the button being visible at all is a Chrome-specific thing, and it's only caused by setting `requireInteraction` to `true`. At least in Firefox and Edge, the button won't show up at all.

As an alternative and assuming you're making use of a Service Worker, you can also trigger the notification using the Service Worker's registration. By that you can also use [additional attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) in the notification's options, like `actions` where you can define a list of buttons that should show up. You can define an `action` for each button and act accordingly in the Service Worker.
The following code works, tested with Chrome 73. Mind the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification#Browser_compatibility).

I hope that helps.

**index.html**

```
<button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
}

function notifyMe() {
  if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then((reg) => {
      var options = {
        body: '<Your Notification Body>',
        icon: '<Your Notification Icon>',
        actions: [
          { action: 'close', title: 'Close' }
        ],
        requireInteraction: true
      };
      reg.showNotification('<Your Notification Title>', options);
    });
  } else {
    Notification.requestPermission();
  }
}
```

**sw.js**

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  if (event.action === 'close') {
    console.log('handle close with button');
    event.notification.close();
  } else {
    console.log('handle notification click');
  }
}, false);

self.addEventListener('notificationclose', (event) => {
  console.log('handle close with arrow');
}, false);
```